# Merge Operation Fails -gpload utility greenplum

Tags: talend, greenplum, hawq

We would like try to describe my problem below:
We have small gpdb cluster. In that,we are trying for Data integration using Talend tool.

We are trying to load the incremental from a table to another table, quite simple... I thought...

**Job Data Flow is**

```
         tgreenplumconnection
                  | 
tmssqlinput--->thdfsoutput-->tmap-->tgreenplumgpload--tgreenplumcommit
```

**Getting error**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot run program "gpload": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at bigdata.sormaster_stg0_copy_0_1.SorMaster_stg0_Copy$2.run(SorMaster_stg0_Copy.java:6425)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:528)
    at bigdata.sormaster_stg0_copy_0_1.SorMaster_stg0_Copy$2.run(SorMaster_stg0_Copy.java:6413)
```

Comment: it means i have to create external table  using gpfdist protocol. is that correct ?

Comment: when i tried to use segment getting  gpfdist connection refused error 111. Is that the problem  not opening gpload process

Comment: Are you able to use gpload in the gbdb cluster ?  If you are able to use gpload for the same command that you are running from Talend ,Then it might be a configuration/environment issue in the Talent side .Check whether the gpload is working fine from the command line

Comment: No it is not working form command line. currently, facing this  issue  psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: I placed socket file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" then did gpdb restart but still it is  saying error. additionally, postmaster.pid is not having any content and file exist

Comment: I tried rebooting the gpdb master machine also but it did not work for me

Comment: @pratheesh_nair  Have You faced this issue earlier?

Comment: Looks like DB is down . You can check in the master logs for the errors and fix the psql connection issue first .Also please check the pg_hba.conf file entries as well.You have to make sure you are able to connect to gpdb and can run gpload command.

Comment: I tried  almost all the way but  database is not  up. andi checked master log as well. Have a postmaster.pid file but no Master segment process running

Comment: Kill or delete all the stale process id and restart the database again .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125452/discussion-between-vickps-and-pratheesh-nair).