# GPDB-psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, hawq

We have the small array of Greenplum database.In that, We have a master node. when I am trying to use PSQL utility

**Getting this error :**

[gpadmin@master gpseg-1]$ psql

```
PSQL: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
We tried
```

on searching for postmaster.pid files.We have removed it.But still, the error remains.

Comment: i think we should keep postgres  as a tag. i have reason for that  i am running on following version gpadmin=# select version();
                                                                                    version


 PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.2.0 build 1) (HAWQ 1.3.0.2 build 14421) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.
4.2 compiled on May 18 2015 17:03:43
(1 row)

Comment: Greenplum is a heavily modified version of a really outdated Postgres - the Postgres tag does not make sense here

Comment: I am  agree . But  if it is using same code of postgres .. I thinK your response on it may be helpful for me while debugging the issue

Comment: The database appears to be down.  gpstart -a

Comment: @JonRoberts  Thanks for reply. So we should go for command  gpstart -a

Comment: I issued the command it is  in progress . I will let you know with output of command.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/ViYgWzWzs7WA9zcn8YF9AD  Here is Output of Command gpstart-a

Comment: Thanks it is working properly.   Can i mark this comment as answer.

Comment: @JonRoberts I am trying to gpload  merge  command . but got this error middle of it.

Comment: @JonRoberts May i talk with  in chat room! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978870/merge-operation-fails-gpload-utility-greenplum?noredirect=1#comment67251566_39978870

Comment: @JonRoberts   can we talk on this

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your PGPORT and source Postgres.sh_path(inside your GPDB).
After that you will be able to do psql and connect to the database.